# inet_ntop causes Warning: inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value

Tags: php

I'm trying to log IP addresses and every now and then I get the following error when using inet_ntop():

> Warning: inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577327/try-inet-ntoprowip-catchgracefully-in-php) I tried the following code but all that happens is that all of my IP addresses are marked as invalid.

```
$is_valid = filter_var($row['ip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) || filter_var($row['ip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6);
```

Is there any way to effectively check a packed IP address to see if it's valid?

Comment: so what's the value in `$row['ip']`. If it's the string `127.0.0.1`, then that's wrong. ntop expects a packed representation, e.g. `$ip = chr(127). chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(1)`

Comment: And technically speaking, **ALL** 32bit ints are "valid" IP addresses. They may not be usable for various reasons, but a 32bit can't be an "invalid" IP.

Comment: No, it's a packed address.  In this case I believe it's 20£.  I did a print $row['ip'] . ' - ' . inet_ntop($row['ip']) . '<br>'; and it's that one that fails when all the others print successfully.

Answer (score 2):

This is late, but I just came across this problem myself, so hopefully it helps someone else.

Your `$row['ip']` variable is the packed (binary) address, but `filter_var` requires the string representation. This is a problem because the only way to get the string representation is to use `inet_ntop` which may give a warning...

The only solution I've found is to suppress the warning every time you use `inet_ntop`. The function returns false so you can check if there was a problem that way. I've wrapped it in a function for easy use:

```
function isValidPackedIP($packed)
{
    $isValid = false;
    $ipStr = @inet_ntop($packed);
    if ($ipStr !== false) {
        $isValid = filter_var($ipStr, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4|FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) !== false;
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ip4 = inet_pton('127.0.0.1');
$ip6 = inet_pton('::1');
isValidPackedIP($ip4); // true
isValidPackedIP($ip6); // true
isValidPackedIP(null); // false, no warning
```